# creating a GUI input option

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement, input, jgrasp

I want to create a GUI and script input option. So I need to add an input argument flag and program logic to use `Scanner` if `false`, JOptionPane if `true`. But I am having trouble doing this.

This is as far as i can get my code because I can't figure out how to get the if else statements and everything to work correctly.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;    

public class UtilsFL {


public static int readInt(String prompt) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int data;

    System.out.print(prompt);
    data = input.nextInt();

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to control your program:
There is an example with variable, which can be changed in main() method
if you call

> readInt("Please int",0)

it will get int from Scanner, and if you call

> readInt("Please int",1)

it will get int from JOptionPane.
Otherwise it'll return -1

There is missing catching exception

```
public static int readInt(String prompt,int type) throws NumberFormatException{
    int data;
    switch(type){
         case 0:
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.print(prompt);
             data = input.nextInt();
             input.close();
             break;
         case 1:
             data=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt));
             break;
         default:
             data=-1;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Not tested